# Issue with $().load

Tags: jquery

I need to load content from an external page when the user clicks on a  tag:

```
$('#anchortag').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#recepient').hide();
    $('#recepient').load('otherpage.php', function(data) {
        $.fancybox(data, {});
    });
});
```

I'm using the jQuery `load()` method to do so, but all I want is the fancybox to open with the external content while now, the content shows in the `#recepient` and in the fancybox. If I try to do: `$.load` (without specifying a target), it fails (the fancybox doesn't show up and I guess the function doesn't work..).

How can I only open the external content in the fancybox with load or another jquery function?

EDIT:
How come this script only works under Chrome and not FF or IE?

Comment: We know it's about jQuery. Please stop tagging your titles.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Ok I'll know for next shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.get(..)` instead. `load(..)` puts the content as innerHTML of the target object, and you don't want that.

Comment: Works fine, thanks! I didn't want to use get at first because I thought it was only useful to load content when I need to pass variables trhough.

Comment: aha. well, it is the way to do a regular GET request via ajax (with or without parameters)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming fancybox has a div some place with html in it, if that is the case you can do something like...

```
$('#anchortag').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#recepient').hide().empty();
    $.ajax({
        url:'path/to/html',
        success:function(data){
            $('#recepient').html(data);
            /* fire fancy box here ...*/
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('an error occurred')
        }
    });
});

    <div id="recepient" style="display:none"></div>
```

**Not tested...** I have done similar things with the native Jquery dialog box.